# How to check Google Play Services is enabled/disabled from code in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I need to check whether mobile has the play services enabled /disabled / available/not installed on it.

I use the following code

```
final int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            Log.e(TAG, GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorString(status));
                      return false;
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorString(status));
                       return true;
        }
```

Even the play services is disable status is returned as "2". How to over come this .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine. Status "2" means that Google Play Services are available but need to be updated. Check ConnectionResult class for all possible statuses:

```
public static final int SUCCESS = 0;
public static final int SERVICE_MISSING = 1;
public static final int SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED = 2;
public static final int SERVICE_DISABLED = 3;
public static final int SIGN_IN_REQUIRED = 4;
public static final int INVALID_ACCOUNT = 5;
public static final int RESOLUTION_REQUIRED = 6;
public static final int NETWORK_ERROR = 7;
public static final int INTERNAL_ERROR = 8;
public static final int SERVICE_INVALID = 9;
public static final int DEVELOPER_ERROR = 10;
public static final int LICENSE_CHECK_FAILED = 11;
public static final int CANCELED = 13;
public static final int TIMEOUT = 14;
public static final int INTERRUPTED = 15;
public static final int API_UNAVAILABLE = 16;
public static final int SIGN_IN_FAILED = 17;
```

Comment: Yeah .. but even the service is disabled manually from background apps ,still it returns 2 instead of 3.

Comment: What if it is both? Can it be that your play services are both disabled and not updated? The method can't return two statuses, so it returns one of those?

Comment: @Singed in case of both, it returns "SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED = 2"

Comment: @Singed I know it's late, but I get the same problem. I have a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43649876/193467

Answer (score 1):

I am using onActivityResult to handle this case.

```
public void callMarketPlace() {
    try {
//if play services are disabled so it will return request code 1 and result code 0 in OnActivity result.
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("market://details?id="+ "com.google.android.gms")), 1);
    }
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 1);

    }
}
```

on Activity Result

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 boolean isEnable = false;

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == 0) {
            if (isEnable){
                isEnable = false;
            } else {
               Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", "com.google.android.gms", null); intent.setData(uri);
                startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                isEnable = true;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note for those trying to figure out how to check if google play services are enabled, the above method

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
```

is now deprecated. Use an instance of GoogleApiAvailability instead

```
GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());
```