# How do you prompt the user to update google play services?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I can easily detect that my device's google play services app needs to be updated, and present the getErrorDialogFragment() to prompt the user to update it with:

```
     GoogleApiAvailability googleApi = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
     mServiceAvailabilityCode = googleApi.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
     if (mServiceAvailabilityCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
          ...
     else {
        if (googleApi.isUserResolvableError(mServiceAvailabilityCode)) {
            switch (mServiceAvailabilityCode) {
                    ....
            case SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
                googleApi.showErrorDialogFragment(SplashActivity.this, mServiceAvailabilityCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                break;
                    ....
                }
```

However, if Google play services is **disabled AND out of date**, then, the user is presented with a dialog with an "Update" button, once the user presses it, the app returns immediately to the onActivityResult, which I then catch the response and request code in OnActivityResult like this:

```
       @Override
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int mServiceAvailabilityCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, mServiceAvailabilityCode, data);
          switch (requestCode) {
          case PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST:
                finish();
                // do i need to launch app manager-> app info for google play services ?
```

So, by the user pressing the "Update" button on the dialog did not launch Android's Playstore and load the "Playstor services" app for the user to update, which I had expected it to do. Pressing "Update" just goes straight back to onActivityResult. This is where I'm confused. Shouldn't Android have launched this for me ? Or do I have to do it myself in OnActivityResult ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is caused by a specific condition when you have 2 issues with Google Play Services (GPS). Because GPS is also disabled Google Play Store (GPT), will not run on the device.

If your Google Play Services is out of date, then calling showErrorDialogFragment using an error code of `ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED`, (error code 2), which works fine.

But if your GPS is both disabled AND out-of-date, then there is an issue with the way `googleApiAvailability` api works.If you call `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` it will return the first error it finds, but it's not necessarily the error you want to resolve first. The problem is knowing that you have another error you need to address first. `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` does not help in this regard.

In my case play services is both disabled, AND out of date. So, the approach is to first call showErrorDialogFragment and you'll get a response error code for `SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED`.

Android will attempt to resolve it by sending a pendingIntent to launch Google Play Store (GPT) to update GPS, but this will fail, as GPT depends on an ENABLED version of GPS. Because you're calling showErrorDialogFragment it will call onActivityResult after it fails to launch GPT.

The next step is codig the onActivityResult. I needed to test for `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` *again*. If you still get the same error code (SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED), then you need to call showErrorDialogFragment *again* in `onActivityResult`, but this time pass it a different error code, `ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED` (error code 3). This will take the user to the app manager to ENABLE google play services first. Then when returning to the app, you need to test for `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` and it should then detect google services is still out of date. If you successfully update the app, `onActivityResult` should allow you to determine that `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` is succcessful and you can continue. Note that you will may need to add a flag that so that you know to test again for google play services compatibility rather than continue executing a startup process.

(So, really what googleApiAvailability should do is return the disabled error first (ie `ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED` aka error code 3), so you can resolve that first before attempting to update GPS.)

Comment: @MSD I have successfully implemented this approach. The trick is using onActivityResult to test for multiple errors in establishing if GooglePlayServices is both enabled and updated.

Answer (score 7):

This is working for me

```
GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    if(googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
       //prompt the dialog to update google play
  googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this,result,PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();

    }
}
else{
  //google play up to date
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The premise of the question is that conventional resolution of google play errors, which is both out of date and disabled is not resolved with your answer. I supplied an answer after posting the question and also doing a lot of testing for a scenario where google play is both out of date, AND disabled. See my answer -1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in which version Google has it fixed, but with the latest 11.6.0 you can get the correct statusCode and the dialog that leads to Settings to enable the Google Play Services.

**Logcat:**

```
11-24 05:48:07.266 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 2070779368
11-24 05:48:07.320 W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_DISABLED, resolution=null, message=null}
```

**Dialog:**
[image]

Comment: The issue was with 9.6+ and the issue was how GPS tries to resolve it. Please read through my solution to get an understanding.

Answer (score -1):

`Google Play Services` are available on `Play Store` to download and update. You can simply open `Play Store`.

[Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en) is link to the services.

What you can do is start activity with `ACTION_VIEW` intent like below

```
String LINK_TO_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = "play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en";
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://" + LINK_TO_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://" + LINK_TO_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES)));
}
```

Comment: How to goto the Google Play Store to update google play services is not the issue.

Comment: Then what is the issue? If opening App Manager is the issue, it will ultimately lead to the Play Store too.

Answer (score -1):

There is also this code:

https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/7554793

Which require:

implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$playServiceAuthVersion"

Comment: Please read through my question and answer to see that the issue is the way GPS handles multiple problems with version and status. The answer you offer does not address the problem.

Comment: In this case can you please change the title of your question? @angryITguy

Comment: I would if stackoverflow assumes that everyone will  answer questions solely on the content of the title, but we don't that's why you should read the details like everyone else.

Comment: @angryITguy if the title is misleading the people who searched or opened this link might be confused and about the answer yea it was my fault.

Comment: Ha. After 2 years and thousands of views you're the first to suggest it's misleading. Go away.