# Cordova App using Firestore does not work on some devices

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-firestore, google-play-services

I have developed a cordova app which inserts documents to firestore. App is deployed on google play store and Apple app store. It works fine with most devices. It fails to insert records to firestore when the device has an older version of google play services. 
Is there anyway to create dependency on a particular version of play services so the app does not even install if the require version is not available on the device. Alternatively, is it possible to invoke update of play services.

Please comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters on Google Play to restrict the installations on devices that do not meet a criteria. See the filters available here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters

For your specific case, you can restrict using the `<uses-library>` filter.

```
<uses-library
  android:name="string"
  android:required=["true" | "false"] />
```

See the complete documentation here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html

To prompt user to update play services check this out: [How do you prompt the user to update google play services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648520/how-do-you-prompt-the-user-to-update-google-play-services)

Hope this helps.