# Asking the user to update Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, safetynet, google-play-integrity-api

Recently, we've integrated Play Integrity in our app to prevent emulators and bots. However, some users cannot generate integrity tokens with the following reasons:

- Binding to the service in the Play Store has failed. This can be due to having an old Play Store version installed on the device.
- Integrity API is not available. The Play Store version might be old, or the application is not allowlisted to use this API.
- Binding to the service in the Play Store has failed. This can be due to having an old Play Store version installed on the device.

**The suggestion from Google for all of these errors is to Ask the user to update his Play Store.** I'm curious is there any way to prompt the user to update his Play Store by redirecting him to the right place in the Play Store app (probably deep link or something)? Of course, we can always just list the steps in-app and let the user do it on his own, but i'm curious if I can improve this process even more?

Comment: Usually the problem is not the Play Store app but the Play Services. There are a lot of posts/answers around on how to ask the user to update Play Services like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648520/how-do-you-prompt-the-user-to-update-google-play-services. By the way there is no public API to redirect the user to update the Play Store app, check this article: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113412?hl=en and "How to update the Google Play Store" section

Comment: @MatPag Thanks for the links. I'm aware that play services might play a crucial role in this. I've been debugging this for a while and i've reproduced this error on my emulator. I'm already checking the Play Services availability on the device and i get the following response: ConnectionResult.Success.
(GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context))

However, when i tried to get integrity token, the API failed with the following error: Integrity API is not available. The Play Store version might be old, or the application is not allowlisted to use this API.

Comment: Yes that can happen, you don't have much control over the Play Store app of your users. You have to make a choice. 1) Preventing users from using your app if they don't have the necessary requirements 2) Ignore the problem (or switch to an alternative) if this is not blocking for your use-case

Comment: What is really funny is that the devices on Test Lab of Firebase are using an outdated version of Play Store and they're throwing this error.